# Re-writing a for loop to a while loop

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to figure out how to translate the following for loop into a while loop, I am very close because the output is fairly similar to the original loop, but spaces are missing. Basically it is printing an X on the screen by displaying small * signs. In my attempt of re-writing it, I get the same amount of * but no spaces, so it prints the next * on the next line, which makes it a straight line.

Edit: I have reassigned j = MIN as suggested, but i also forgot to mention that the question that is asked to me is that I have to convert the for to a while loop, and replace the series of if-else statements with only one if-else-if-else statement.

Here's the original:

public class Practices 
{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    final int MIN = 1;
    final int MAX = 7;
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = MIN; i<=MAX; i++)
    {
        for (j = MIN; j<=MAX; j++)
        {
            if (i==j)
                if (i == (MIN+MAX)/2)
                    System.out.print("o");
                else
                    System.out.print("*");
            else if (i+j == MIN+MAX)
                System.out.print("*");
            else
                System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

Here is my attempt:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    final int MIN = 1;
    final int MAX = 7;
    int i = MIN;
    int j = MAX;

    while (i <= MAX)
    {
        j = MIN;
        while (j <= MAX)
        {
            if(i == j && i == (MIN+MAX)/2)
            {
                System.out.print('o');
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            if (i + j == MIN + MAX)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            j++;            
        }
        System.out.println();
        i++;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried stepping through your code to see exactly where the difference occurs? This shouldn't be very hard to figure out with a little trial-and-error, either.

Comment: dont combine if statements.. just keep it as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int MIN = 1;
        final int MAX = 7;
        int i = MIN;
        int j = MAX;

        while (i <= MAX) {
            j = MIN;
            while (j <= MAX) {
                if (i == j)
                    if (i == (MIN + MAX) / 2)
                        System.out.print("o");
                    else
                        System.out.print("*");
                else if (i + j == MIN + MAX)
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" ");
                j++;
            }
            System.out.println();
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Revise with just one if:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int MIN = 1;
    final int MAX = 7;
    int i = MIN;
    int j = MAX;

    while (i <= MAX) {
        j = MIN;
        while (j <= MAX) {
            if ((i == j) && (i == (MIN + MAX) / 2))
                System.out.print("o");
            else if ((i + j == MIN + MAX) || (i == j))
                System.out.print("*");
            else
                System.out.print(" ");
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention in the post that the question that is asked to me is that I have to convert the for to a while loop, and replace the series of if-else statements with only one if-else-if-else statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `j = MIN;` instead of `j = MAX;` before the nested `while` loop.

Also, the nested `if`-`else` construct is not equivalent to the original.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    final int MIN = 1;
    final int MAX = 7;
    int i = MIN;
    int j = MIN;

    while (i++ <= MAX)
    {
        while (j++ <= MAX)
        {
            if (i==j)
                if (i == (MIN+MAX)/2)
                    System.out.print("o");
                else
                    System.out.print("*");
            else if (i+j == MIN+MAX)
                System.out.print("*");
            else
                System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention in the post that the question that is asked to me is that I have to convert the for to a while loop, and replace the series of if-else statements with only one if-else-if-else statement.